# Manufacturer DCIM folder format

Tags: file-management

I'm pretty sure I used to have a camera that would create a different folder each day (I think it used the day-of-the-year as the three digit code), which I think is a great idea, but can't remember if I'm accurate in my remembering, or even who the manufacturer would have been.

Does anyone know which (if any) cameras support seperating photos by the date they were taken?

Cheers

Comment: Sony NEXs (now ILCE) can create a different folder every day with a date-dependent folder name.

Comment: So.... Stack Exchange is generally terrible for a) requests to point to an answer in another location and b) making lists of things. Can you rephrase this to just ask for the thing you're looking for?

Comment: @mattdm, I guess I'm after cameras that will automatically seperate photos by date taken. I shall reword my question

Comment: In any case, a list of cameras with a feature is _also_ a request for a list, and generally, list questions like this turn into an ugly mess on this site, so they're generally off-topic.

Comment: *That* said, are you sure this is really what you need? Why not use software to rename the photos to a scheme of your liking on import?

Comment: @mattdm, no, it's not what I "need", as yes, I manually seperate them now. Is it a big task? Not really, but just looking to see if there was anything to make my life a little easier.

Comment: I'm not suggesting _manually_ separating them. I'm suggesting using software to _automatically_. See for example [this answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/52861/1943).

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I'm after cameras that will automatically seperate photos by date taken.

I'm note sure if this helps or not, but using a computer ( or tablet ) you can list, reorder or sort your files based on file date.  Every image ( file ) from your camera will have the time and date it was created on the card it is stored.

That time and date is also written "inside" the image in the EXIF data.  Most photo applications can read that and some will allow you to e.g. view all the files based on date.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using that to seperate the photos, I was hoping to just be able to rename the folders before copying them to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Some cameras do it by default. Other cameras don't do it by default, but do give the user an option to turn such a feature on. Other cameras may not be capable of such.

But unless there is a specific reason why you desire to do this in camera it is extremely easy to segregate photo by date taken as you import them to your long term storage device, or even at a later date. The timestamp that a photo is taken is stored in the EXIF information. The file creation and file modified date included in the file information is also in the file properties on the memory card.